# Unable to implement pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I came across a pseudocode which I am unable to implement because, I am unable to understand it:

```
i, c := 0,0;
do i ≠ n →
    if v = b[i]           → c, i := c + 2, i + 1
       c = i               → c, i, v := c + 2, i + 1, b[i]
       c ≠ i ^ v ≠ b[i]    → i := i + 1
    fi
od
```

I think that tis pseudocode is about finding the value v which has occurred more than *n* / 2 times in b[].

Comment: OK...but what's the question?

Comment: I think this question belongs on Programmers.SE.

Comment: What exactly you cannot understand? The notation of pseudo code or why does it work correctly?

Comment: What are you trying to implement ! What does this pseudo code supposed to be doing("sorts number", " kills racoons" ?

Comment: @JayD I have already mentioned in the question what does the pseudo code do.
It is related to finding the value v which have occured more than n/2 times in an array b[n]

Comment: forget this pseudocode, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three conditions in the `if` are alternatives, they should be translated to an `if-else if-else` chain.
The assignment-like statements `c,i,v := c+2, i+1, b[i]` are multiple assignments, as far as I know like the Python multiple assignments, so the `i` in `b[i]` refers to the old value of `i`. That yields

```
// n and v are initialised to something sensible, hopefully
i = 0;
c = 0;
while(i != n) {
    if (b[i] == v) {
        c = c + 2;
        i = i + 1;
    } else if (c == i) {
        c = c + 2;
        v = b[i];  // conjecture that the b[i] on the RHS refers to the old i
        i = i + 1;
    } else {
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Since `i` is incremented in every branch, we can lift that out, and get

```
for(i = 0, c = 0; i != n; ++i) {
    if (b[i] == v) {
        c += 2;
    } else if (c == i) {
        c += 2;
        v = b[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: But what have you done with the condition :
c ≠ i ^ v ≠ b[i]
You have neglected it completely !!

Comment: That condition is a consequence of the two others being false. It translates to `c != i && v != b[i]`, which is exactly the case if neither of the two first conditions is true, so in the first loop, it's the final `else`, in the second loop, it need not appear because in that case the only thing that is done is incrementing `i` which happens in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, this isn't what I expected to ever see. It looks like Dijkstra's do-od notation (not sure what's a good reference, maybe this: http://www.cs.grinnell.edu/~stone/courses/compilers/introduction-to-Dijkstra.pdf).

Roughly what this is doing is a series of guarded checks.  If some condition holds, then do the implication.  As for implementing something in do-od notation, I'm not too sure.  Something along the lines of:

```
i = c = 0;
while (i != n) {
    if (v == b[i]) {
        c = c+2, i = i+1;
        if (c == i) c = c+2, i = i + 1, v = b[i];
        if (c != i || v != b[i]) i = i + 1
    }
}
```

No idea what those intermediate variables are, and I've always conceptualized do-od programs as something closer to hardware (with everything running and testing in parallel).  Good luck

Comment: I have no idea what n, v, or b should be set as before starting...See if figuring out the do-od notation helps at all.

Comment: Those assignments are supposed to happen concurrently, so you're using the wrong `i` to index `b[i]` in the `c == i` case. Also, the `if` has three independent guards, so the `v == b[i]` test should just be one of a three-way branch.